# Which one is best? Domain redirect or alias?

Tags: web, seo

I have a very recently purchased website say www.existingdomain.org (both domain name and hosting purchased with the same hosting company). I have not yet submitted this to search engines as the website development is still in progress.

Now, I have realized that the name www.existingdomain.org is not so good, so want to change the name say like www.newdomain.org (just a domain name only without hosting plan) and require that when search for www.newdomain.org, it should get redirected to www.exisitngdomain.org.

1) I wanted to know, if I can achieve the domain redirection by purchasing www.newdomain.org with say some other domain registrar (different from my www.existingdomain.org) for example godaddy.com as a parked domain without any hosting and then following the steps for forwarding/redirecting this to www.existingdomain.org? Please clarify.

2) For this redirection, is it enough to modify the settings for the www.newdomain.org at godaddy.com only OR any updates need to be done to the www.existingdomain.org configuration also?

3) I read many reviews that Google treats domain alias as duplicate content. Hence, wanted to go for domain redirection. Since my www.existingdomain.org was purchased very recently and still development is in progress and not yet submitted to search engines, hope domain redirection is fine. Please advise which one is best domain redirection or alias in my case.

4) Also, please advise whether domain alias or redirect is best with respect to search engines.

Please, provide clarifications to my 3 points above using www.existingdomain.org and www.newdomain.org for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just purchased the domain then just scrap it and start fresh with the domain you really want, no reason in wasting time doing redirects and aliasing.